# How to assign a (row) numpy.matrix to a column in a numpy.matrix

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

The relevant code is below. I create a zeros matrix which here happens to be a 2X2 matrix. Then I march through a data file to populate the matrix with random numbers within the range of each column of the input data set. This works, except that the output matrix is transposed, and I'd rather do it right. Please see the comments in the code.

```
centroids = mat(zeros((k,n))) #create centroid mat
print('centroids: \n', centroids, '\n', type(centroids))        
print('starting for loop for j in range(%s)' %(n))
    for j in range(n):#create random cluster centers, within bounds of each dimension
        print('\n')
        # get the min value in the jth column
        minJ = min(dataSet[:,j]) 
        # get the max value in the jth column
        maxJ = max(dataSet[:,j]) 
        # the range of values is max - min
        rangeJ = maxJ - minJ
        print('col %s, min = %s, max = %s, range = %s' %(j, minJ, maxJ, rangeJ))
        # create a 'column' of random values for each colum
        col =  mat(minJ + rangeJ * random.rand(1,k))
        print('column %s is %s, type is %s' %(j, col, type(col)))
        # assign columns to column in centroids
        # DOES NOT WORK, assigns to rows.
        centroids[j] = col
        print('   ==> centroids: \n', centroids)
    return centroids
```

Here is the output. Notice that the output array /should/ be [[3.08,.434],[-1.36,-.203]].

```
centroids:
 [[0. 0.]
 [0. 0.]]
 <class 'numpy.matrix'>
starting for loop for j in range(2)


col 0, min = [[-5.379713]], max = [[4.838138]], range = [[10.217851]]
column 0 is [[ 3.08228829 -1.35924539]], type is <class 'numpy.matrix'>
   ==> centroids:
 [[ 3.08228829 -1.35924539]
 [ 0.          0.        ]]


col 1, min = [[-4.232586]], max = [[5.1904]], range = [[9.422986]]
column 1 is [[ 0.4342251 -0.2026065]], type is <class 'numpy.matrix'>
   ==> centroids:
 [[ 3.08228829 -1.35924539]
 [ 0.4342251  -0.2026065 ]]
================

centroids follows:
[[3.08228829]
 [0.4342251 ]]
[[-1.35924539]
 [-0.2026065 ]]
```

Here is what I have tried:

```
centroids[:,j] = col
centroids[0:1,j] = col
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 68, in <module>
    centroids = randCent(dataList, 2)
  File "run.py", line 51, in randCent
    centroids[0:1,j] = col
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (1,2) into shape (1,1)
```

How can I do this without transposing the matrix? Thanks.

My script file is below:

```
 #run.py

from numpy import *
import sys
import importlib

#fun defs############################################

def testFun(name):
    print("Hello, %s" %(name))


def getData(fileName):
    data = []
    fr = open(fileName)
    for line in fr.readlines():
        curLine = line.strip().split('\t')
        #print('A ',curLine, type(curLine)) ## gets a list of strings as a list
        fltLine = [float(i) for i in curLine] ## converts strings to floats
        #print('B ', fltLine, type(fltLine)) ## returns a list of floats
        data.append(fltLine)
    return data


def distEuclid(vecA, vecB):
    return sqrt(sum(power(vecA - vecB, 2))) #la.norm(vecA-vecB)


dataSet = [[3.141592653589793, 1.4142135623730951], [2.718281828459045, 1.618033988749895]]

def randCent(dataSet, k):
    print('calling randCent(dataset, %s)' %(k)) 
    dataSet = mat(dataSet)
    n = shape(dataSet)[1]
    print('columns n is %s and groups k is %s and type(dataSet) is %s' %(n, k, type(dataSet)))
    #print(dataSet)
    centroids = mat(zeros((k,n))) #create centroid mat
    print('centroids: \n', centroids, '\n', type(centroids))
    print('starting for loop for j in range(%s)' %(n))
    for j in range(n):#create random cluster centers, within bounds of each dimension
        print('\n')
        # get the min value in the jth column
        minJ = min(dataSet[:,j]) 
        # get the max value in the jth column
        maxJ = max(dataSet[:,j]) 
        # the range of values is max - min
        rangeJ = maxJ - minJ
        print('col %s, min = %s, max = %s, range = %s' %(j, minJ, maxJ, rangeJ))
        # create a 'column' of random values for each colum
        col =  mat(minJ + rangeJ * random.rand(1,k))
        print('column %s is %s, type is %s' %(j, col, type(col)))
        # assign columns to column in centroids
        # DOES NOT WORK, assigns to rows.
        centroids[0:1,j] = col
        print('   ==> centroids: \n', centroids)
#    print('==> centroids: ', centroids)
    return centroids
    



#exe code#############################################
print("loading file run.py")
testFun('Bob')

dataList = None
dataList = getData('testSet.txt')
#print(dataList, type(dataList))

print('variable dataList has been initialized: %s' %(dataList is not None))
centroids = randCent(dataList, 2)
print('================\n')

print('centroids follows:')
print(centroids[:,0])
print(centroids[:,1])
```

Comment: That's a whole lot of code. Are you sure ALL of that is needed for a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: What's wrong with transposing?  And why are you using `mat`, as opposed to a 2d `ndarray`?

Comment: @hrokr the original code was not an MRE because it was missing variables and imports, so code was added to make it functional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assignment to a 2d array:

```
In [500]: A = np.zeros((2,3), int)                                                                   
In [501]: A[0,:] = np.arange(3)                                                                      
In [502]: A[:,1] = [10,20]                                                                           
In [503]: A                                                                                          
Out[503]: 
array([[ 0, 10,  2],
       [ 0, 20,  0]])
In [504]: A = np.zeros((2,3), int)                                                                   
In [505]: A[0,:] = [1,2,3]                                                                           
In [506]: A[:,1] = [10,20]                                                                           
In [507]: A                                                                                          
Out[507]: 
array([[ 1, 10,  3],
       [ 0, 20,  0]])
```

Try the same on `np.matrix`:

```
In [512]: M = np.matrix(np.zeros((2,3),int))                                                         
In [513]: M                                                                                          
Out[513]: 
matrix([[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]])
In [514]: M[0,:] = [1,2,3]                                                                           
In [515]: M[:,1] = [10,20]                                                                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-515-e95a3ab21d7f> in <module>
----> 1 M[:,1] = [10,20]

ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2) into shape (2,1)
In [516]: M[:,1] = [[10],[20]]                                                                       
In [517]: M                                                                                          
Out[517]: 
matrix([[ 1, 10,  3],
        [ 0, 20,  0]])
```

Why the difference?  Because once a matrix, always a matrix:

```
In [518]: A[:,1]                                                                                     
Out[518]: array([10, 20])
In [519]: M[:,1]                                                                                     
Out[519]: 
matrix([[10],
        [20]])
```

To assign a value to a (2,1) shaped space you need a (2,1) value.  Broadcasting can only add an leading dimension, (2,) to (1,2), not (2,1).

A flatiter can be used to assign a 1d array:

```
In [520]: M[:,1].flat                                                                                
Out[520]: <numpy.flatiter at 0x7f57b127dda0>
In [521]: M[:,1].flat = [100,200]                                                                    
In [522]: M                                                                                          
Out[522]: 
matrix([[  1, 100,   3],
        [  0, 200,   0]])
```

Comment: Thank you. Python isn't my primary language but I use it from time to time. I treasure these little moments of nuttiness. "flatiter" Who would'a thunk?